# apache spark - failed to connect to remote spark stand-alone system

Tags: java, apache-spark

My standalone spark is running on ec2 instance. But when I tried connecting to that through Java code, I got an error. Java code is:

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App_Name")
            .setMaster("spark://172.31.2.165:4040");
            //.set("spark.ui.port","4040");
    JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

And the error is:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /172.31.2.165:4040
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:216)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:183)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information: /172.31.2.165:4040
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- By default you should use port 7077 to connect to the master, port 4040 is for the web UI
- Make sure port 7077 is reachable from wherever you run you Spark job, for instance open it in the security group that the master is in when you run it from outside EC2

Comment: I changed port to 7077. Now the code is 'SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App_Name")
            .setMaster("spark://172.31.2.165:4040");' Port 7077 is opened in the security group. Still I am getting the same error.